# Delete a dynamically created directory on exit

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a directory created dynamically during a shiny session. The directory name and path is inside a reactive value. How do I delete this directory on exiting the session?

Working example:

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("display")
)
server <- function(input,output,session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(newpath="./temporary")

  fnr <- reactive({
    dir.create(rv$newpath)
    return(paste("Directory created"))
  })

  output$display <- renderPrint({
    fnr()
  })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    unlink(rv$newpath,recursive=TRUE)
    ##unlink("./temporary",recursive=TRUE)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

This gives an error because a reactive value (`rv$newpath`) is called outside of reactive context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?reactiveValues`:

> If not in a reactive context (e.g., at the console), you can use
>   isolate() to retrieve the value:

You should be able to just surround your reactive value in `isolate` to get it's value even if you're not in a reactive context:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    unlink(isolate(rv$newpath),recursive=TRUE)
})
```